# How do I use Input.GetButton() without getting several jumps at once? Unity 2D Character Controller C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made loads of 2D games where you're a thing on a screen and you jump around etc, but with my latest project, triangle run (geometry dash but worse), I want to be able to hold down the mouse and the character jumps at an even pace, you know, like in geometry dash, so instead of using `Input.GetButtonDown` I replaced it with `Input.GetButton`, and I put a `return;` after the `if` statement so only one `if` could be ran per `Update()` (which is the function it's in), but this made it so anything but the quickest of taps would launch the player 10-20x the normal jump height. I tried loads of different ways of making sure the `if` statement would only be ran once per `Update()`, which gives the charactercontroller ample time to check if the player's grounded in order to allow or prevent the jump, so I'm not sure why it's launching me up. Edit: It all worked fine with `Input.GetButtonDown`.

Here's the whole code for the player movement so far, I just started the game so that's why there isn't much yet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController2D controller;
    bool jump = false;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public Transform transform;
    private float moveY = 0f;
    private int jumpCounter = 0;
    private bool jumpIf = true;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && jumpIf) // if we press the jump button
        {
            jump = true; // set jump bool to true (see void fixedupdate for more)
            jumpIf = false;
        }
        else
        {
            jump = false;
        }
        jumpIf = true;
        return;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() // called a set amount of times per second, used with physics movement etc lol
    {

        controller.Move(0f, false, jump); // move in which direction, are we crouching, are we jumping
        jump = false;
        moveY = rb.velocity.y;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, moveY);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the `if`, it's very messy because I ended up trying all sorts of things.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Your `jumpIf` thing does nothing .. it is reset **every frame** so your `jump` is set to `true` every frame ... don't know how the jumping is handled in that Character controller thingy exactly but I guess if you only call it once in FixedUpdate it should be fine actually since internally afaik it has a grounded check .. but maybe the grounded radius is just to big?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `GetButtonUp` in `FixedUpdate` with the if statement?
I had similar problems with interactions in `Update`. Using `GetButton` on `Update` would make the game to execute the jump every frame since you start pressing the jump key, whereas with `GetButtonUp` the action will execute only when the jump key is released.
Something like this might work:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")) // if we press the jump button
            {
                jump = true; // set jump bool to true, in case you want to use it for an animation,etc.
               //Jump code here.
                controller.Move(0f, false, jump);
                moveY = rb.velocity.y;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, moveY);
            }
}
```

Either that or using a [CoRoutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) in `Update` with a `yield return new WaitForSeconds()`.

Comment: Sounds like OP rather wants the user to be able to simply hold down the Jump button and do single jumps as soon as the player object touches the floor ... That would be the reason for switching to `GetButton` instead of former using `GetButtonDown`